# PHP rc.local bootup script only working partially, running it manually - no problems

Tags: php, linux, boot, rc

I have a script that I need to be run once the system boots up. I have therefore placed the script inside my `/etc/rc.local` file

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

screen -dmS PythonLoader /usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/html/scripts/load.py
php '/var/www/html/cron/bootup.php'

exit 0
```

Inside my `/var/www/html/cron/bootup.php` file I have the following code, which downloads a file from a remote host

```
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, TRUE));
$remoteFileSize = $head['content-length'];
echo (file_put_contents($this->serverZipLocation . basename($url), fopen($url, 'r')) == $remoteFileSize) ? true : false;
```

My problem is that the above code only downloads around 60% of the remote file, where after it just stops script execution. Looking at my `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log` yields nothing other than a message about the server being started.

If I however run the script manually by just loging into a terminal as root and write `/etc/rc.local` there is no problems at all.

For convenience the `/var/www/html/scripts/load.py` which is also loaded inside the `/etc/rc.local` file has no problems.

Why doesn't this work?

EDIT: I've tried now to put a `sleep 120` just before the first line in `rc.local`, and this seems to make it work. It could seem that something required isn't ready when the scripts are run? Maybe network?

Comment: Could it be a timeout when running `rc.local`? Have you tried spawning on the background? (not delay boot also):  `php '/var/www/html/cron/bootup.php' &`

Comment: Is there a specified max execution time for rc.local or so ?

Comment: Don't know to be honest... but no logs or errors make me think that something/one killed the process... do you need it synchronous?

Comment: I've just added the `&` char after script line like you said, and it seems to be working actually.. It doesnt time out anymore and continues the download! The & char tells the system to run the script in background i assume ?

Comment: yes it forks. If you are quick enough, after booting do a `ps -ef | grep php` and you should see it.

Comment: Maybe i was too quick there.. The third time i tried it halted half way through the download. I dont get it. Why does it work sometimes and other times not. It makes no sense